# I can not find mesh panel or mesh check box which should be in the fluid tap

Tags: fluid-simulation

I can not find mesh panel or mesh check box which should be in the fluid tap

first, I succeeded in making fluid particles, but for the next step, I stucked.
Many tutorials say that I should click the Mesh checkbox to bake mesh, but there is no such box..
Where can I find it? Plz help,,

[image: I succeeded in making fluid particles, but..]

[image: I can not find the Mesh panel and check box]

Comment: Thank you so so much!,, it was a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Click the little arrow beside the 'Liquid' checkbox which will expand the panel and you'll find the Mesh entry on that panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You guys made me keep motivated.

Comment: You're welcome!